# JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) type in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm using typescript and want to deep copy my object.
I used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) method here is the code

`const dataClone: DataType[] = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data) );`

My data is an array with object which type is DataType[].
But I'm getting warning that I used any type and it is - Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.

Where I missed the type?

I tried to put type after variable declaration

`const dataClone: DataType[] = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data) );`

Comment: You would use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to achieve this instead

Comment: Consider using [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) instead of using JSON to deep clone your objects.

Comment: Please provide the complete snippet of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your type is lost to `string` when you use `JSON.stringify` then to `any` when you use `JSON.parse` so you have to use a type assertion to tell the compiler it's of type `DataType[]` like this:

```
const dataClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) as DataType[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but it was a problem i came across today.
If you have a interface for the dataClone already, you can write it like this:

```
const dataClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) as dataCloneInterface;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the spread operator

```
const dataClone: DataType[] = [...state.initialData]
```

Comment: That does a shallow copy and will give very different results.